# GNU date output specific time

Tags: date

I have a date command that outputs the last day of the previous month:

```
date -d"-1 day 1 $(date +%b)"
```

Outputs:

```
Sun Sep 30 00:00:00 BST 2018
```

How can I change the time part to be 23:59:59 on the same date?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solutions:

```
 date -d "$(date +%b) -1.0 sec"
```

Notice the usage of a float and not an integer for the subtraction. This is to avoid timezone problems.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies, sadly it gave me an error.
I got things working with:

```
EPOCH=$(date -d "-1 day 1 $(date +%b)" +%s)
END=`echo $EPOCH +86399 | bc -q`
```

Which gives me the EPOCH at 23:59:59 on the last day of the previous month.